# Typescript: union type with index

Tags: typescript

I'm working on some pagination config for a table and trying to create proper types for my request.
Here are my types:

```
interface Data {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
}

interface Sort<T> {
  order_by: keyof T;
  sort_order: "asc" | "desc";
}

interface Filters {
  [key: string]: React.Key[];
}

interface Pagination {
  page: number;
  page_size: number;
}

type Request<T> = Sort<T> & Pagination & Filters;
```

Later I'm creating objects of each type and trying to put them all together:

```
const sort: Sort<Data> = {order_by: 'prop1', sort_order: "asc"}
  const pagination: Pagination = {page: 1, page_size: 10}
  const filters:Filters = {prop1: [2, 55]}

  const request: Request<Data> = {
    ...sort,
    ...pagination,
    ...filters
  }
```

But it throws an error:

```
Type '{ page: number; page_size: number; order_by: "prop1" | "prop2"; sort_order: "asc" | "desc"; }' is not assignable to type 'Request<Data>'.
  Type '{ page: number; page_size: number; order_by: "prop1" | "prop2"; sort_order: "asc" | "desc"; }' is not assignable to type 'Filters'.
    Property 'page' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Key[]'.
```

I was also trying to use `Exclude` and `Omit` utility types on `Filter` to remove the keys of other 2 types, but that didn't help much.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without manually setting keys in `Filters`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is currently possible in TypeScript (there's no "K not in keyof T"). I'd consider doing requests as `type Request<T> = Sort<T> & Pagination & { filters: Filters }` instead

Comment: @KevinTaylor Yeah, after a few hours of research and debugging it appears not to be possible. 
So now I'm just using a workaround with separate props for `sort`, `pagination` and `filters` merging them all together in `axios`'s request params.